# The data types image and varbinary(max) are incompatible in the equal to operator

Tags: c#, sql-server, linq, asp.net-mvc-5

One of my asp.net mvc project, i am trying to save an image to SQL Server Database table : [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zCSu2.png)

In my C# Controller, I am uploading a picture and **converting it to byte[] array** so that I can save it to database.My Code is like below.

```
    [HttpPost]
    [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
    public ActionResult Create([Bind(Include = "CustIDNO, EDate,LetterNo,LetterFrom,LetterType,Comments, ValueTime")] WarningPic warningPic, HttpPostedFileBase img)
    {
        byte[] fileData = null;

        if (img != null)
        {
            //Here i am converting image to byte array
            using (var binaryReader = new BinaryReader(img.InputStream))
            {
                fileData = binaryReader.ReadBytes(Request.Files[0].ContentLength);
            }

        }

        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            warningPic.FileName = warningPic.CustIDNO.ToString();
            warningPic.Picture = fileData;
            warningPic.SlNo = 9;

            db.WarningPics.Add(warningPic);

            db.SaveChanges();


            return RedirectToAction("Index");
        }

        return View(warningPic);
    }
```

Everything should by okay , but i am getting a mysterious error like :
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WTgUL.png)

```
The data types image and varbinary(max) are incompatible in the equal to operator.
```

Description: An unhandled exception occurred during the execution of the current web request. Please review the stack trace for more information about the error and where it originated in the code.

Comment: Despite it's name, `image` is *not* an appropriate data type to be using here. Quite apart from [anything else](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/data-types/ntext-text-and-image-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017): "ntext, text, and image data types will be removed in a future version of SQL Server. Avoid using these data types in new development work"

Comment: Then what data type should be use to store image on database table?

Comment: I changed the data type from Image to varbinary(max) and the problem is gone. thanks to you. Actually i am using a pre existing legacy database with existing old data.So I had to think twice to change data type.

Comment: @ÆĀmAnup, the legacy `image` type can store the same binary values as `varbinary(MAX)` but be aware that existing code that uses `WRITETEXT`, `UPDATETEXT`, or `READTEXT` will not work with `varbinary(MAX)`.